# How can I map dynamic variables to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I want to map the data I'm getting from DB, but there is a dynamic variable -
[image]

I don't know what the variable is gonna be how can i map it with dynamic option?

The `Crypto` is an interface -

```
class Crypto extends Sequelize.Model<IDBCryptoAttributes> implements IDBCryptoAttributes {
  public id!: number;
  public BTCUSD!: string;
  public ETHUSD!: string;
  public LTCUSD!: string;
  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `any`?

Comment: @onzinsky im not using any. and i think i need to map dynamically

Comment: So what is `cryptoPrices`? An array of `Crypto` I assume? And what is your problem exactly? I'm not sure I get the "map it with a dynamic option". Maybe it's just me

Comment: @onzinsky look at the answer Elson commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OR:

```
cryptoPrices.map(r => r.BTCUSD || r.ETHUSD || r.LTCUSD)
```

I am assuming that 2 variables are empty and only one has a value.